# Number Theory: How to prove this statement?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove for natural number $n$ there are natural numbers $k_1,k_2,...k_n$ such that all of them are greater than $1$, each pair of them are co-prime, and we can write $k_1 k_2 ... k_n - 1$ as product of two consecutive numbers.

Any hints how to prove the statement?

Answer (score 3):

This is problem 1 from USAMO 2008, and many solutions can be found [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2008_USAMO_Problems/Problem_1#Solution_1)